# Combine order method on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm triying to order an Active Record query using to fields.

I need order first by created_at and then using priority field (include 1,2,3... values).

I try with this code but dosen't works.

```
@products = Product.all.limit(10).order("created_at").order("priority")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.order(:created_at, :priority).limit(10)
```

Comment: Dosen't works sandip, i get "can't add a new key into hash during iteration"

Answer (score 3):

`all` gives you an array, not a relation. Just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Does `@products = Product.all.limit(10).order("created_at, priority")` work?

Comment: get the error "can't add a new key into hash during iteration"

Comment: Ups, I did not see the 'all'. I just copied it. The 'all' is wrong.